# С# MVC 4. Передача кастомных полей в Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Всем привет, нужна помощь

Имеется страница с возможностью добавления полей (JQuery)

При создании нового поля оно создается с уникальным Name.

Собственно вопрос: как получить значения созданных кастомных полей в Controller?

По сути там будут значения типа **Key->Value**

Есть подозрения, что можно как-то добавлять новые поля как объекты модели, но не знаю как

**Model**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProduct", "Catalogue", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="block-content collapse in">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="create-product">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name) <br/> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price) <br/> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Currency)</td>
                <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Currency) <br/> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Currency)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageData)</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="Image"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="custom-params">
                <td>Универсальные параметры</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="custom-parameters" onchange="showCustomForm(this)" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Сохранить"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

**JS**

```
function createParam() {
    $('#custom-manager').after('<tr name="custom-' + fieldCount + '"><td><input type="text" name="key-' + fieldCount + '" /></td><td><input type="text" name="value-' + fieldCount + '" /></td></tr>');
    fieldCount++;
}
```

**Как это все выглядит в итоге**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал сам, добавил в модель 2 свойства string[] Key и string[] Value, переделал создание полей с присвоением имени вида Key[i] и Value[i]